# What is the best way to perform a subtraction on Cassandra by cqlsh request?

Tags: cassandra, cql3, database, nosql

I am trying to make a cqlsh request on Cassandra. The idea is analyse the average length from different 'gene' registers that had been annotated in a genome. After enter the data, I have this athaliana.tab table:

```
 id                                   | chr | comments          | end      | orf | sense | start    | type
--------------------------------------+-----+-------------------+----------+-----+-------+----------+------
 d2ab2520-6734-11e5-955c-234085c1edec |   1 | gene_id AT1G16340 |  5590338 |   0 |     - |  5590241 |  CDS
 d4169c00-6734-11e5-955c-234085c1edec |   1 | gene_id AT1G16610 |  5676495 |   . |     - |  5676429 | exon
 a8c792c0-6734-11e5-955c-234085c1edec |   1 | gene_id AT1G07485 |  2301889 |   0 |     + |  2301665 |  CDS
 3bd5c0a0-6735-11e5-955c-234085c1edec |   1 | gene_id AT1G51980 | 19326916 |   . |     - | 19326733 | exon
 263b5b60-6735-11e5-955c-234085c1edec |   1 | gene_id AT1G44990 | 17007808 |   . |     - | 17007542 | gene
 67989a50-6735-11e5-955c-234085c1edec |   1 | gene_id AT1G63110 | 23405144 |   . |     + | 23404821 |  UTR
 26f7f4a0-6735-11e5-955c-234085c1edec |   1 | gene_id AT1G45180 | 17101207 |   0 |     + | 17101109 |  CDS
 3743dc70-6735-11e5-955c-234085c1edec |   1 | gene_id AT1G50840 | 18841644 |   0 |     + | 18840965 |  CDS
 e5099940-6734-11e5-955c-234085c1edec |   1 | gene_id AT1G20620 |  7145780 |   . |     + |  7145691 | exon
 2ba30620-6735-11e5-955c-234085c1edec |   1 | gene_id AT1G48180 | 17793717 |   . |     - | 17792449 | gene
```

The idea is obtain the subtraction between end-start columns data and calculate the average. I have tried by this way:

```
SELECT avg(end-start) FROM athaliana.tab WHERE chr = '1' AND type = 'gene';
```

but it results in:

```
SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:14 no viable alternative at input '-' (SELECT avg([end]-...)">
```

Some ideas? Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cassandra is designed for maximum read and write efficiency and has no built-in support for functions applying to multiple columns such as `plus` or `minus` nor for *aggregates*, i.e., functions applying to multiple rows, such as `avg` or `count`.

Until recently, the workaround was to store the results of your functions in a separate column and perform aggregations in your own application code.

However, Cassandra 2.2 and 3.0 now offer *User-Defined Functions* (UDFs) and *User-Defined Aggregates* (UDAs). You can now define your own functions, then have Cassandra invoke them for you. See the CQL spec chapters on [UDFs](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL-2.2.html#udfs) and [UDAs](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL-2.2.html#udas) or [this blog post](http://christopher-batey.blogspot.fr/2015/05/cassandra-aggregates-min-max-avg-group.html).

First, create the following functions and aggregates:

```
USE athaliana;

CREATE FUNCTION minus (x int, y int) RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT RETURNS int LANGUAGE java AS 'return x-y;';

CREATE FUNCTION avgState (state tuple<int,bigint>, val int) CALLED ON NULL INPUT RETURNS tuple<int,bigint>  LANGUAGE java AS '
    if (val != null) {
      state.setInt(0, state.getInt(0)+1);
      state.setLong(1, state.getLong(1)+val.intValue());
    }
    return state;
';

CREATE FUNCTION avgFinal (state tuple<int,bigint>) CALLED ON NULL INPUT RETURNS double LANGUAGE java AS '
    double r = 0;
    if (state.getInt(0) == 0) return null;
    r = state.getLong(1);
    r /= state.getInt(0);
    return Double.valueOf(r);
  ';

CREATE AGGREGATE avg(int) SFUNC avgState STYPE tuple<int,bigint> FINALFUNC avgFinal INITCOND (0, 0);
```

Then your query could be rewritten this way:

```
SELECT avg(minus(end,start)) FROM athaliana.tab WHERE chr = '1' AND type = 'gene';
```

Note that you should only use aggregates on a single partition key; if this is not the case, a warning will be raised.