# CQL - can't do arithmetic operations

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-4.0

Good afternoon,

i'm currently getting started with Cassandra and CQL and i'm encountering a problem.
I made a very simple data base and i would like to do some arithmetic operations between the columns (addition, multiplication...). When i try to do so i get the following error :

```
"no viable alternative at input '-' "
```

From what i've read, arithmetic operations weren't supported for long by Cassandra, but the [official documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/operators.html) seems to say otherwise.

So my question is : Am I doing it wrong ? Or are these operators still not supported ?

I am using Cassandra 3.11.2 and cqlsh 5.0.1. My query is

```
Select ProductName, NetIncome, ProductionCost, (NetIncome - ProductionCost) from globalsales.Rentability group by ProductName;
```

Where NetIncome and ProductionCost are both columns of type int.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that doc was written a bit prematurely.  Currently arithmetic is not supported as a part of CQL.  It is covered in the JIRA project under [CASSANDRA-11935](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11935).

That ticket will be applied to the Cassandra 4.0 release, of which there is not currently an ETA for.

**Edit 20210824**

With Cassandra 4.0, arithmetic operations between columns are now possible.  The query above should now work.

```
> SELECT productname, netincome, productioncost, netincome - productioncost FROM rentability;

 productname         | netincome | productioncost | netincome - productioncost
---------------------+-----------+----------------+----------------------------
 Stihl 2018 Chainsaw |    625.95 |          82.14 |                    543.81

(1 rows)
```

Comment: Thank's ! I saw some solutions with user-defined functions, i'm going to try that.

Comment: @J.C Yes, that's one thing you could try.  I actually answered a UDF question a little while back that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913729/how-to-get-current-year-on-cassandra

Comment: Thank you, i got what i wanted using a example from an other post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859406/what-is-the-best-way-to-perform-a-subtraction-on-cassandra-by-cqlsh-request).